# Passing sys.argv[1] from a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python program which takes a directory with video files as `sys.argv[1]` and perform various `ffmpeg` operations. However, it does not iterate over subdirectories. To get across this, I created a list with the code below which contains path to subdirectories. 
Is there a way that each element from the list is passed as `sys.argv[1]` along with `ffmpeg.py`.

```
import os, sys
firstarg=sys.argv[1]

a = []
for dirpaths, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(firstarg):
    if not dirnames:
       a.append(dirpaths)
print (a)

['Desktop/Remote/Remote2', 'Desktop/Remote/Remote1']
```

So what I want is, that each element from the list passed as `sys.argv[1]` along with `ffmpeg.py` in a new terminal window, for example,

```
python3 ffmpeg.py Desktop/Remote/Remote2/
python3 ffmpeg.py Desktop/Remote/Remote1/
```

UPDATE:

I have added the command below to the code and it seems to work. Is there a better way to achieve this,

```
for i in a:
    call(["python", "Desktop/ffmpeg.py", i])
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use Glob. It has functionalities of iterating through a directory and it's sub-directories. It will follow the pattern supplied as well.

Ex:
Grabbing any JSON file in a directory tree. Then you could use os.execv() to execute your ffmpeg.py script and pass the file variable (which is the path to the file) as an argument

```
import os
import glob
folder = sys.argv[1]
for file in glob.iglob(folder + "**/*.json", recursive=True):
    os.execv(path_to_ffmpeg.py, file)
```

When you run this script, all you would have to provide is the path to ffmpeg.py as an argument.

See [Glob Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html) and [os Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) for more. Hope this helps!